# JavaScript cannot set constant as a argument for function on express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, constants

I am working on learning the MEAN stack with Angular2.  I have postman set up so that I can test whether everything is connecting.  In my terminal I put a **console.log** down to see what I am getting in req.body.  The response is as expected.  Also, below I am passing the **constant username** into an exported function

```
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) =>{
  const username = req.body.userName;
  const password = req.body.password;
  console.log('req.body', req.body);  // ** req.body.userName 'test', password: 'test

  //inside router.post
  User.getUserByUserName(username, (err, user) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('username', username);  //undefined
```

The exported function works like so

```
module.exports.getUserByUserName = function(username, callback) {
  const query = {username: username}
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}
```

Nothing fancy.   just passing a username argument and callback.

Unfortunately, username is undefined.  Not sure what I am missing.  everything is hooking up and hitting break points.  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dividing the code like that will be harder for us to understand what's going on. Is `getUserByUserName` inside the `router.post`?

Comment: Did you try to print the req.username?

Comment: Yes,  I will edit my code.

Comment: @israel.zinc.  I am able to print both the password and username above **getUserByUserName**.

Comment: Is your request body a json? If it's a string you won't be able to parse it.

Comment: Are you using [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) or something equivalent?

Comment: Fixed!!!!!!!! userName instead of username.   This is probably worth deleting.